# Ativar dados Moveis

Tags: android

Quero um botão que ative e desative os dados moveis atravez do meu app. A wifi ja consigo manipular, porem os dados moveis não encontrei a forma.

Comment: Poderia postar o código que você usou para ligar a wifi?

Comment: Segue codigo para ativar wifi                                                                   
   WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)  getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);